# How to not create beans based on other beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have a configuration class in which it's annotated with @Configuration. 2 beans get created. These beans are used annotated with @Profile hence if the profile is set to `prod`, then it'll get instantiated.

I am using Lombok, one of my classes is annotated with `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and I have several `private final` fields which essentially Lombok autowires in the background. From the beans it autowires, only one method in that class depends on those beans and that method should only be used in the production env essentially.

The problem I am having is that how can I tell lombok to not instantiate the beans?

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("PROD")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClientFilterConfiguration {



@Bean
public Client createClient() {
    ... return client;
}

@Bean
public Filter createFilterBean(){
    ....return filter;
}
```

}

Class:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class ClientController {

   private final Admin admin;
   private final AdminDuo adminDuo;
   private final Client client;
   private final Filter filter;

   public void clientPurchase(){
       ...
   }

}
```

Getting the following error:

> ...required a bean of type 'com.example.Client' that could not be found.
>   
> Action:
>   Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.Client' in your configuration.

Only one method in that class is relying on the Client and Filter bean so is there a way preventing that error?

Comment: Put that method in another Controller, also annotated with `@Profile("PROD")`. Or change the two argument types to Optional<Client> and Optional<Filter>.